# regex to highlight XML values

Tags: c#, .net, regex, xml, uwp

**DISCLAIMER:** I know that using regex on xml is risky and generally a bad idea, but I can only feed regex into my syntax highlighting engine, and I can't spend the ressources required to create a new system just for xml-based languages.

---

So I'm trying to use regex to get the values inside XML tags, as such:

```
<LoremIpsum>I NEED THIS PART</LoremIpsum>
```

I thought this would be nice and easy, and I could just use `(>.*<\/)`. It works perfectly on any online regex tester, however, as soon as I try using it in .NET, it completely messes up, and I end up getting a completely unpredictable output. What would be the correct way to do this, in one regex expression, considering I'm using .NETs `System.Text.RegularExpressions`?

Comment: 1) Do not escape the forward slash. 2) Set the capturing group around the subpattern you need to get. 3) In XML, `<` cannot be left unserialized, thus, rely on it as a delimiter rather than `>`. Use [`Regex.Match(input, @">([^<]*)<").Groups[1].Value`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3e(%5b%5e%3c%5d*)%3c&i=%3cLoremIpsum%3eI+NEED+THIS+PART%3c%2fLoremIpsum%3e).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because .NET Regex are greedy. My suggestion would be to use non greedy `.*?` or `[^<]` instead of `.`:

```
(>.*?<\/)
(>[^<]*<\/)
```

Like that it can't move over a `<`.

Answer (score 0):

You never define what `it completely messed up` means, but try doing this:

```
(>.*?<\/)
```

The `?` in `.*?` makes it a non-greedy match.  By default, regular expressions operators *greedy* meaning they will match as much as possible.  The non-greedy form matches *as little* as possible.  To see the difference, match 'is test of' against both forms:  With `(>.*<\/)` you will match:  `is <a>test</a> of`.  With `(>.*?<\/)` you will match `is <a>test`.

If you want to avoid any XML tags in the match, then you should use @ThomasWeller's solution.